# PRESTASHOP 1.6 al crear un módulo, cómo enlazar form y frontcontroller?

Tags: formularios, prestashop

Estoy empezando con prestashop, he creado un módulo en el que casi todo funciona correctamente y se muestra en pantalla al pulsar mi tab.

El problema es que no consigo hacer que el formulario pase por el `postprocess()` del `FrontController` al hacer el submit.

**prueba/prueba.php**:

```
public function install()
{
    Configuration::updateValue('PRUEBA_LIVE_MODE', false);

    return parent::install() &&
        $this->registerHook('header') &&
        $this->registerHook('backOfficeHeader') &&
        $this->registerHook('displayHomeTab') &&
        $this->registerHook('displayHomeTabContent'); 
}

public function hookDisplayHomeTabContent()
{
    global $smarty;
    $this->context->controller->addCSS($this->_path.'/views/css/prueba_content.css');
    $this->context->controller->addJS($this->_path.'/views/js/prueba.js');

    $this->smarty->assign(array( 'mess'=>'')));
    return $this->display(__FILE__,'prueba_content.tpl');
}
```

**prueba/views/templates/front/prueba_content.tpl**:

```
<form action="{$link->getModuleLink('prueba', 'pruebafrontcontroller')|escape:'html'}" method="post">
        {if ($mess!="")}
            <h4 class="title_block">
                {$mess}
            </h4>
        {/if}
        <input type="submit" name="submit_requestform" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

**prueba/controllers/front/pruebafrontcontroller.php**:

```
  class PruebaFrontController extends ModuleFrontController 
  {

    private $mess = '';
    //public $php_self = 'prueba';
    //public $ssl = true;

    public function postProcess()
    {
        if (Tools::isSubmit('submit_requestform'))
        {
            $this->message = 'SUBMIT PULSADO';
            $this->context->smarty->assign('mess', $this->message);
        }
    }

    public function initContent()
    { 
        parent::initContent();
        $this->message = 'FORMULARIO CARGADO';
        $this->context->smarty->assign('mess', $this->message);
        $this->setTemplate('prueba_content.tpl');
    }

  }
```

Gracias!!

Answer (score 0):

En el nombre de la class del FrontController debes poner el nombre de tu modulo al principio.

```
class {nombre_modulo}PruebaFrontController extends ModuleFrontController {
    ...
}
```